# How can I show both calenders (T-Clock an Windows) in T-Clocks

Tags: windows-10, t-clock

I'm using [T-Clock](https://github.com/White-Tiger/T-Clock/releases/) to show a customized view of the windows watch. It's possible to show the standard windows calender on a single left click but I'm not sure how to show the T-Clocks calender for double click. Inside the options you can only choose "calender":

[image]

And a different option lets you choose which calender you want to use (Windows or T-Clocks):

[image]

Is there a way to use both? (Note: I searched but did not find an answer in [T-Clock's own forum](https://www.donationcoder.com/forum/) yet. I will post the question there as well if no one here has an answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a workaround by using the `Execute command` option in combination with `C:\Tclock\XPCalendar.exe`. This opens the T-Clock calender regardless of the settings for the default calender.